# How to convert double values to string in a text field

Tags: java, netbeans, textfield

I want to do the average of 9 textfields and also the sum of them and place them in 2 other textfields by using a button, currently this code doesnt displays anything in the other textfiels. If i put anything, for example "A" instead of "%.Of" it would display the "A" in the textfield but not the average or the sum. Please i need help with a code that would work, dont mind if i need to change a lot.

This is what im working with:

```
private void jButton_RankingActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
double R[] = new double [14];

R[0] = Double.parseDouble(jTextField_Math.getText());
R[1]= Double.parseDouble(jTextField_English.getText());
R[2] = Double.parseDouble(jTextField_Spanish.getText());
R[3] = Double.parseDouble(jTextField_Biology.getText());
R[4] = Double.parseDouble(jTextField_Physics.getText());
R[5] = Double.parseDouble(jTextField_Chemestry.getText());
R[6] = Double.parseDouble(jTextField_PE.getText());
R[7] = Double.parseDouble(jTextField_Humanities.getText());
R[8] = Double.parseDouble(jTextField_Technology.getText());

R[9] =  (R[0]+R[1]+R[2]+R[3]+R[4]+R[5]+R[6]+R[7]+R[8])/ 9;
R[10] = R[0]+R[1]+R[2]+R[3]+R[4]+R[5]+R[6]+R[7]+R[8];

String Average = String.format("%.Of",R[9]);
jTextField_Average.setText(Average);

String TotalScore = String.format("%.Of",R[10]);
jTextField_TotalScore.setText(TotalScore);

if(R[10]>=50)
{
    jTextField_Ranking.setText("Superior");
}
else if (R[10]>=41){
    jTextField_Ranking.setText("Alto");
}
else if (R[10]>=34){

    jTextField_Ranking.setText("Basico");
}                                               
else if (R[10]<=33){

    jTextField_Ranking.setText("Bajo");
```

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more about asking questions that will attract quality answers.  You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49466030/edit) to include more information.

Comment: 1) variable names should NOT start with an upper case. Some are correct, others are not. Be consistent!. 2) `If i put anything, for example "A" ` - the character "A" can't be parsed to a number, so your code isn't being executed. Did you add any System.out.println(...) statements in your method to see if the statement to set the text of the "average" text field is being executed? Do some basic debugging first.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned that an `A` would print, it follows that `jButton_RankingActionPerformed` is being called.  The issue you have is the format string you are using to print the total and average.  You have mistakenly chosen the capital letter `O` rather than the number zero.

Replace this (which contains a capital letter O):

```
String.format("%.Of",R[9]);
```

With

1) No decimal will be printed: i.e. 50.2 would be 50

```
String.format("%.0f",R[9]);
```

2) Or perhaps you want to see one decimal place like 50.2

```
String.format("%.1f",R[9]);
```

Also a very small optimization is:

```
R[9] =  (R[0]+R[1]+R[2]+R[3]+R[4]+R[5]+R[6]+R[7]+R[8])/ 9;
R[10] = R[0]+R[1]+R[2]+R[3]+R[4]+R[5]+R[6]+R[7]+R[8];
```

Could be replaced with:

```
R[10] = R[0]+R[1]+R[2]+R[3]+R[4]+R[5]+R[6]+R[7]+R[8];
R[9] = R[10] / 9;
```

or use a loop to calculate R[10]. (to add R[0] to R[8])